# What is the need of using webpack and making bundle while react app can work without this?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I could not understand why we are using webpack while react app can work without this ? Webpack creates a bundle which puts all JS into single file so this make app faster ? I did not find my answer so I asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Using Webpack with React enables -

- You can use different loaders for sass, less, postcss etc
- You can use different plugins to optimise your build such as Uglify, HotModuleReplacement, Chunks etc

There are many more advantages to use webpack which you can find [here](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/)

Need of bundle.js -

If you ever developed a SPA (Single-Page-Application), where ever it was on Angular, React, Vue or something else, You probably noticed that all the hard work you’ve put into your app goes to one minified .js file and one .css file. Those files contain all your dependencies and functionalities of the app. Thats the core concept behind SPA, everything you need is downloaded initially on accessing the app and then you don't go to the server again and all the routing is handled on UI. This is posible because bundle.js contains the code of entire app.

Comment: Do we use webpack only for `minified files` ?